# 10.3.23-MariaDB QUERY Syntax Error, INTO OUTFILE, help me solve it

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, file-io

So I'm trying some MYSQL queries on my linux machine, but this query won't work

```
MariaDB [exploit]> select * from items union select 'Hello World',null,null,null,into outfile '/tmp/test.txt';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'into outfile '/tmp/test.txt'' at line 1

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: the  `INTO` clause goes before the `FROM` clause. It is a bit tricy to use with `UNION`: you need to put it in the last `UNION` member (and the entire result from the query is written to the out file).

So:

```
select * from items 
union all select into outfile '/tmp/test.txt' 'Hello World', null, null, null
```

For more information, see the documentation:

- [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)
- [`UNION` restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)